# How can import a .sql file in app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I m experimenting with GAE, and I m looking for a way to import an .sql file in app engine datastore. I found on GAE site ways to import CSV ans xml files:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

but nothing about .sql.

I ve also came across the so called "jiqlAdmin Data Querying tool" that claims to import .sql files in google `s datastores:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/Sfy3jmWhYfI

Anybody has tried tool this? Does it work? Do you have any other suggestion?

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is just using SQL with App Engine, I would check out [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), which works great with App Engine.

If you just want your data in the datastore, converting it to CSV and uploading it as per the first link might be a good choice. This will not work if you have things like foreign keys as they will refer to IDs in your old SQL database. You also probably won't be happy with your data if it's arranged in such a way that using a `JOIN` is the only way to make sense of it.

Since it sounds like you are just getting started, I think Google Cloud SQL is the better option.